# vue 3 unexpected token ... on chrome versions below 60

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So I am trying to launch my app below chrome 60 version. But I get this error:
[image]

App is built on vue 3. And also this is my `.babelrc`:

```
"plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
        "@vue/babel-plugin-jsx"
 ],
```

Thought it was about object spread operator but I have plugin for that. Have any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: just curious why r u trying to launch ur app below chrome 60 version

Comment: No certain reason. Just trying to be able to launch it as low as possible.

Comment: @Dr.Junior but why? There is no reason to launch apps on that old browsers... :)

Comment: What is your `browserslist`? Do you target Chrome 60 or only more recent versions?

Comment: My targets are inside `.babelrc`: ```"presets": [["@babel/env",{"targets": {"browsers": [
"Chrome >= 49","FireFox >= 60","Safari >= 11"]}}]]```